# Automatic display age after filling out birth date with a format of YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: javascript

Actually I already posts it here. It's solved by someone here but after I tried it again now, it fails again. Please help.

```
function ageCount() {
var date1 = new Date();
var dob = document.getElementById("dob").value;
var date2 = new Date(dob);
var pattern = /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/;
//Regex to validate date format (dd/mm/yyyy)       
if (pattern.test(dob)) {
    var y1 = date1.getFullYear();
    //getting current year            
    var y2 = date2.getFullYear();
    //getting dob year            
    var age = y1 - y2;
    //calculating age                       
    document.getElementById("ageId").value = age;
    document.getElementById("ageId").focus ();
    return true;
} else {
    alert("Invalid date format. Please Input in (dd/mm/yyyy) format!");
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Please post your HTML

Comment: How it fails? Where have you posted it? What have you tried after that?

Comment: I just use it to other computer. It just don't run. It echo the Invalid date format.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use your code, and to me it looks like it's working. I put it in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenLangeraert/HL47T/) and it seams ok to me.

Although the age calculation is rather rough, something like the following code would calculate exacter ages, since someone whose birthday is still this year will have an age shown that he will have on his next birthday.

Something like this would calculate the age:

```
function  calculateAge(date1 , date2) { 
    var ageDifs = date1 - date2.getTime();
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifs); // miliseconds from epoch
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}
```

Your error message **Invalid date format. Please Input in (dd/mm/yyyy) format!** does not match your input format **yyyy-mm-dd.** Which one do you want to use?

I created an extended [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenLangeraert/HL47T/1/) for that

**In case you need dd/MM/yyyy** I created an new jsFiddle, doing a better date validation and more accurate age calculation

[dd/mm/yyyy jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenLangeraert/HL47T/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is perfect just need to change the regular expression:-

So instead of

```
var pattern = /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/;
//Regex to validate date format (dd/mm/yyyy)       
if (pattern.test(dob)) {
```

Only write

```
if (dob.match(/^(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{4})$/)) {
```

and the date format will be

```
dd-mm-yyyy
```